# juju stops on "running machine configuration script" MAAS/JUJU/ real servers

Tags: juju, maas

i am getting this issue when doing juju bootstrap, please note that this is on a rack of 10 servers running MAAS,

and here it hangs for all eternity.

```
Creating Juju controller "maas-controller" on cloud-maas/default
Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.8.5 for amd64
Launching controller instance(s) on cloud-maas
- 4dq38h (arch=amd64 mem=8G cores=4)  
Installing Juju agent on bootstrap instance
Fetching Juju Dashboard 0.3.0
Waiting for address
Attempting to connect to 192.168.10.201:22
Connected to 192.168.10.201
Running machine configuration script...
```

thanks